FastAPI repository pattern and Celery connection
Has anyone ever worked with FastAPI Repository pattern and Celery ?
I am having a hard time to call a service within the Celery application. Since you have to use dependency Injection for Fast API, you can't access the services, anyone who know how best to do this ?
Do I need to connect the celery configuration on to the Fast API instance.
For-example, I have this setup in the core/celery/celery.py;
from celery.app import Celery

from core.celery.config import settings


    def celery_app():
        app_celery = Celery()
        app_celery.config_from_object(settings, namespace="CELERY")
        app_celery.autodiscover_tasks(['core.celery.jobs'], force=True)
    
        return app_celery

then in the api/init.py :
app = FastAPI(docs_url=docs_url, redoc_url=None, default_response_class=ORJSONResponse)
app.add_exception_handler(KeycloakError, keycloak_error_handler)

app.router.route_class = RouteWithLogging

# CORS settings
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=[str(origin) for origin in settings.cors_origins],
    allow_origin_regex=settings.cors_origin_regex,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

then I have Services, Repository, and Router, of course I can't share them all, but I tried to access the Service in a task.
@app_celery.task
def automated_trainings_email_reminders(dependency: ....):
    service = TemplateService(.....)

NOTE:

Don't focus too much on the syntax, but please focus on the structure of connecting a Service and Celery in a repository pattern.

